# SendFrom feature of Bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind

I have a server and I would like to host multiple wallets of bitcoin. I synced the node and it's fully synced.

I want to **handle the balance of all the accounts individually,** so that while sending coins, the node won't send the balance of any other account.

I made few experiments like I tried to first **createrawtransaction**, then **fundrawtransaction** then **sign & finally sendrawtransaction**. 
The issue is that it sends the balance from default account and results in -ve balance of any account (this is wrong).

Then I tried to send btc using sendfrom. this works fine (deducts balance from the account) but when I made transaction, I didn't get confirmations still after 3 hrs. The fee given was $5 and the transaction amount was $20.

Using same fee and transaction amount, I made transaction through create,fund,sign & send rawtransaction & it got accepted.

How to make these transactions accepted using sendfrom?

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: bitcoin-cli sendfrom "myaccount" "toaddress" "amount"

Comment: @Feathercrown here is the send from code. 
Don't mind , the code is not the issue. Issue is that why the sendfrom transaction is not listed on blockchain although I got txid.

Comment: @Feathercrown the transaction I did through create , fund , sign & send raw transaction got confirmations in 5-10 mins with same fee i.e $5 . But didn't get confirmations through sendfrom . 
And I cant use create, fund, sign & send because they create transaction through default wallet i.e "" account